# Capistrano "Permission denied (publickey)." error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, gitlab

I know that this problem has been asked many times, but I can't get it sorted (I'm a beginner).

What I'm trying to do is to deploy my rails application to my production server using capistrano. I stored my project on a directory on gitlab. Everything was working perfectly until I moved my application in an other gitlab repository (git@gitlab.com:myusername/xxxxxx.git).

I think I set up my deploy.rb file accordingly :

```
set :application, "xxxxxx"
set :user, "yyyyy"
set :repository,  "git@gitlab.com:myusername/xxxxxx.git"
```

But when I try to deploy it, I get the permission error :

```
[xxxxxx.com] executing command
[xxxxxx.com] env PATH=/home/kar/.rbenv/shims:/home/kar/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/xxxxxx/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/xxxxxx/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 97ff4f45240a680c1d278325d7ac1871536c8091 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@gitlab.com:myusername/xxxxxx.git /var/www/xxxxxx/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/xxxxxx/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 97ff4f45240a680c1d278325d7ac1871536c8091; fi'
** [xxxxxx.com :: err] Permission denied (publickey).
** [xxxxxx.com :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Could you please propose me some tests to find out from where the issue comes ?
Is there any key to add on my server ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the capistrano 3 plugin that is created solely for the purpose of troubleshooting problems like this one: [capistrano-ssh-doctor](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor).

The plugin outputs a report with found issues and suggested next steps.

Comment: Are there quick checks to try before trying this ? As I said I'm a bit new and don't want to mess up everything by adding a new gem

Comment: And I'm using capistrano 2